# roslaunch default package

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a .launch file inside a package, is it possible to omit the package name in a  tag if the node package is the same as the package the launcher lives in? I mean, I have a launcher with lines like this:

`<launch>`

`<rosparam command="load" file="$(find my_package)/config/config.yaml" ns="configuration" />`

`<node pkg="my_package" name="node1" type="node1.py" output="screen" />`

`<node pkg="my_package" name="node2" type="node2.py" output="screen" />`

`<node pkg="my_package" name="node3" type="node3.py" output="screen" />`

`<node pkg="my_package" name="gui" type="gui.py" output="screen" required="true"/>`

`</launch>`

If I want to change the package's name, I'll have to change the pkg argument of all the nodes. Is there a way to omit that, or at least to replace with something like "this" (or "self", as Python programmers use)?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174088/roslaunch-default-package/) by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-19**:
My guess is no and if it was available I'd advise against it. If someone copies the launch to adapt it, everything will break. Changing all occurrences is an easy task for search and replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use roslaunch args, but I would completely advise against that. Changing the name of a package is not something to be taken lightly, as it affects all downstream uses (roslaunch files, packages that find this package through catkin, dependency calculations, etc).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2